# Newline character (\n) duplicates when writing a file with Python?

Tags: python, file, newline

I'm writing a simple program that sends bytes to a server (UDP connection), the server echoes the bytes back, and then I write the echo on an output file. The main functions are these:

```
def communication_into_server(s, size, filename):
    f = open(filename, 'rb')
    while True:
        line = f.read(size)
        if line == b'':
            break
        s.send(line)
    f.close()
    s.send(b"EOF")

def communication_from_server(s, size):
    g = open("output.txt", 'w', encoding="utf-8")
    while True:
        line = s.recv(size)
        print(line.decode("utf-8"))
        if line == b'EOF':
            break
        g.write(line.decode("utf-8"))
    g.close()
```

Some sample text is this:

```
This is some sample text
with a single newline character.
```

and its output looks like this:

```
This is some sample text

with a single newline character.
```

Apparently, \n characters are being duplicated somewhere. Note the print() on the second function. It prints this:

```
This is some sample text
with a single newline character.
```

without the extra newline character, so the problem doesn't appear to be in the connection. If I change 'w' to 'a' while opening the output file, nothing changes. What am I missing?

Comment: If you do a byte dump on the output file, does it actually contain `\n\n` after the first text?   Or does it contain `\r\n`?

Comment: \r\n the sample file, \r\r\n  the output file

Comment: Some systems use/expect `\r\n` as a newline, while others treat _both_ `\r` and `\n` as newline characters (hence the double-newline). And believe it or not, this is _still_ **much** better than the way it once was.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, saving markdown files using python, and the spaces were being duplicated on each save.
I simply encoded the string before saving it in a file using the `encode` method:

```
body = body.encode()
# now it can be saved into a file...
```